# How to find and change CSS values using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.2.

I need to find and change CSS values to use 98% of the screen, to fit large listings of data with many columns that are falling out of the limits of the content selector.

I found content selector that is contained inside `col-md-12` bootstrap selector

The properties inside `col-md-12` are:

```
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
```

Today the application is centered on the screen, I would like to:

- Align padding: 4 from left and 4 from right.
- Enable content selector to fill all the space.

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

1.) Download the version of bootstrap you are attempting to use and include it in your project's directory

2.) Include it in your app with a `<link>` tag

3.) Do whatever you want to it... you can customize it to your liking...

Comment: note: delivering assets like Bootstrap is best done over a CDN but in this case I think my solution above is the easiest and fastest work around

Comment: how can i find the selector who is containing the content selector and if this is the one i can change to fitt 98% of the screen

Comment: mmm .container-fluid or .container maybe? I guess I am not exactly sure what you are asking at this point

Comment: @MaxwellLasky He seems to be asking a more basic question. Rigo - Use Google Chrome to inspect your content and find what sets the width. Then edit the css with that selector

Comment: miros last comment is going to be your best bet for troubleshooting this @Ângelo Rigo

Comment: Yes inspecting with chrome i first found content and before i have col-md-12, before i have row but did not found width atribute may i will set and go by trials

Comment: i have container with auto to margin-right and left this would do the trick if i found the outer html element

Comment: Just found the solution a custom main into a separate file. Thank´s